# Can't use crossdomain.xml on CloudFront

Tags: rtmp, amazon-cloudfront, crossdomain.xml

I'm using a streaming distribution on CloudFront to serve media via RTMP. Obviously I want to restrict the crossdomain.xml file but CloudFront is only serving it's default one. The docs give instruction on how to overwrite their default -> I have a public, non-restricted crossdomain.xml in the root of my s3 bucket (the one with the media files), but it still serves out the default. What am I missing?

It should not be serving the default here: http://sixqlk56v2jbq.cloudfront.net/crossdomain.xml

Comment: Could you please provide a pointer to the documentation explaining _how to overwrite their default_? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The docs give instruction on how to overwrite their default

I'm not aware of this currently, to the contrary, see [Restricting Access Using Crossdomain.xml](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RTMPStreaming.html#Streaming_CrossDomain):

> The Adobe Flash Media Server crossdomain.xml file specifies which
>   domains can access media files in a particular domain. CloudFront
>   supplies a default file that allows all domains to access the media
>   files in your streaming distribution, **and you cannot change this
>   behavior.** *[emphasis mine]*

So while an annoying limitation indeed, I'm afraid you are out of luck currently, except if this turns out to be a documentation bug; you might want to file a respective support and/or feature request in the [Amazon CloudFront Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=46&start=0) accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for my delay in responding. I apparently didn't have reply notifications turn on. The documentation I was referring to was in the AWS forums from other users. I reached out for help there but recieved no replies.

Comment: Apparently Amazon changed their docs sometime using my testing, wild coincidence. It was not clear before that you can not have a custom crossdomain.xml. However I know sites on cloudfront that are using a custom one, they must have been grandfathered in from a previous version.